# Vue js send image blob between child components and show preview of image

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have Three Component with this structure

```
1.ParrentComponent(
  -1.ChildComponent
  -2.Child
)
```

1.Child component is loading image via file input and making preview in that controller. after  i click submit button i need to send this blob image to second child and show that preview there.

My problem is when  i sent image to second child url in image is the same but image not show just alt is showing

1.Child:

```
<template>
    <div id="insert-component">
        <div id="insert-new" >
            <h2 class="text-md-left">Nová kategória</h2>
            <div class="mt-2 text-left">
                <a href="#" id="img-button" class=" d-flex flex-wrap" v-on:click.stop="loadImage()">
                    <img v-bind:src="category_img" alt="logo" id="preview">
                    <input type="file" class="d-none" id="load-category-image"  v-on:input="handleFileSelected">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" >Pridať obrázok</button>
                </a>
                <small class="text-danger d-none error" id="img-error">Súbor musí byť png, jpg alebo jpeg</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-2 text-left">
                <div>
                <label for="category_name">Názov kategórie:</label>
                <input type="text" required name="name" class="form-control" v-model="category_name" id="category_name">
                <small class="text-danger d-none error"  id="name-error">*Názov je povinný</small>
                </div>
                <label for="category_description" class="mt-2">Popis kategórie:</label>
                <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="4" v-model="category_description" id="category_description">
                </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block my-2" v-on:click.prevent="submit()">Pridať kategóriu</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "InsertComponent",
        props: [ 'updateTableData' ],
        data: function () {
            return {
                category_name: "",
                category_description: "",
                category_img:"/storage/images/no_image.png",
                file:null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            loadImage(){
                document.getElementById('load-category-image').click();
            },
            submit(){
                if(this.checkIfEmptyById('category_name')){
                    this.showErrors('name-error');
                    return
                }
                let item = this.createNewItem();
                this.updateTableData(item);
                this.clearInputs();
            },
            createNewItem(){
                return {
                    category_img: this.category_img,
                    category_name: this.category_name,
                    category_description: this.category_description,
                    created_at: null,
                    updated_at: null,
                    id: null,
                    file:this.file
                };
            },
            clearInputs(){
              this.category_name="";
              this.category_description="";
              this.category_img="/storage/images/no_image.png";
            },
            handleFileSelected() {
                let loadedFile = document.getElementById('load-category-image').files[0];
                if(this.checkIfFileIsImage(loadedFile))
                {
                    this.file = loadedFile;
                    //this.category_img="/storage/images/"+loadedFile.name;
                    this.changeImagePreview();
                }
                else{
                    //show image error
                    let imgError = document.getElementById('img-error');
                    imgError.classList.remove('d-none');
                }
            },
            checkIfFileIsImage(file){
                const acceptedImageTypes = ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
                return acceptedImageTypes.includes(file['type']);
            },
            changeImagePreview(){
                let loadedFile = document.getElementById('load-category-image').files;
                this.category_img = URL.createObjectURL(loadedFile[0]);
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Second child:

```
<template>
    <div class="text-center">
        <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields">
            <template v-slot:cell(category_img)="data">
                <img v-bind:src="'/storage/images/'+data.item.category_img" alt="img" width="50px" height="50px" class="rounded-circle">
            </template>
            <template v-slot:cell(category_name)="data">
                {{data.item.category_name | capitalize}}
            </template>
            <template v-slot:cell(category_description)="data">
                {{data.item.category_description | capitalize}}
            </template>
            <template v-slot:cell(actions)="data">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info mr-1"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>
                </div>
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:"TableComponent",
        props: ['tableData'],
        data() {
            return {
                fields: [
                    {
                        key: 'category_img',
                        label:'Img',
                        sortable: false
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'category_name',
                        label:'Name',
                        tdClass: 'capitalize-first-letter',
                        sortable: true,
                        variant: 'dark'
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'category_description',
                        thClass: 'd-none d-md-block',
                        tdClass: 'd-none d-md-block text-left',
                        label:'Description',
                        sortable: false,
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'actions',
                        sortable: false,
                    }
                ],
                items: this.tableData
            }
        },
```

Parrent component just passing data between these component it is not important data are passing good. Problem is just that image. Thx for help

This is looks like: (right side child 1, left side child 2)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct if Im wrong but in your `Child` you are passing a function as a prop which in vue is an anti pattern. You should always follow the `props down event up` design pattern.

Anyway, continue to your problem. On your `Child 2` you have the following line

```
items: this.tableData
```

This line will assign the value of `this.tableData` to `items`. This is only assigned on the created hook part of the component. If this table data changes (which I'm fairly sure it does) the `item` variable won't be updated. You should have a watch watching the prop and re-assign to `item`

```
watch: {
  tableData: (value) => {
    this.item = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1.Tsx for tip with that pattern. 2:Yes but my component is updating now. There is not problem in updating new data. That works now. Problem is only in that image as you can see on image above...  On right side is preview okay but on left side in column img as you can see on first two rows is not.  On right side img is just blob ( I just choose it from my pc and it is only preview, not saved yet)

Comment: Have you tried inspecting it on chrome and seeing the value of the `:src='...'`?

Comment: Ouuu now i can see it... i have duplicate start of src address on left side. Thx for help

Comment: @YoungL. If this answer helped you solve your problem mark it as correct answer